# jQuery DataTable with filtering for duplicates of SQL table

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, spring-boot

In the next step of my app, I have to model a particular type of table to show.

A quick summing of actual state of art: the app is developed using Spring Boot, JDBCTemplate, Bootstrap, Ajax, jQuery Data Table.

The current task is: in our db, one of the table is ***events***, that store data about events of our networks pc. Next to search for all events (complete), we want another page on our app: the ***"Today Events"***. This page show only the events of current day.

How to query db for current day is not an issue, I know how to do this.
The problem is: when I query db, I may have some row with same host but different type of events (one of events filed is "type", that show which type of events is the one showed). This is an example of results when I ask host name, events type and host os:

[image: events today sample query]

As you can see, the first 2 host have 2 different type of events: Achille has OS and Applications, Aiace File Integrity and TCP Services.

When we show the data in our app, using jQuery DataTable, we want not this showing: the results table must have this header:

[image: events today for web app]

What we want is: for all hosts, show them and their OS ***only one time***; then, if there are events of a certain type, an element (which element is another story, for now suppose a simple symbol as 'X') must appear. Using the previous result table, the output may be:

|Host   |OS   |OS|FileIntegriry|Services|Running Services|TCPServices|Appli.|

|Achille|Linux| X|             |        |                |            |    X|

|Aiace  |Linux|  |     X       |        |                |    X       |     |

|Anubi  |Win  |  |             |        |        X       |            |     |

```
Now, my DAO class has a method that perform the query to obtain all the events of the current days, that is:

public List<Events> getTodayEvents()
    {
        /**
         * This is the string that contain the query to obtain the data from join of
         * hosts and events with aggregator operations.
         */
        String SQL = "SELECT * FROM hosts JOIN events ON hosts.id = events.host_id WHERE DATE(events.date) = CURDATE()";

        /**
         * The list containing the results is obtained using the method query on jdcbtemplate, giving in in input to it the query string, the array of object 
         * containing the input variable of the method and the rowmapper implemented.
         */
        List<Events> theEvents = jdbcTemplate.query(SQL, new HostAndEventsMapper());

        return theEvents;
    }
```

and this method is used from my controller, in this method:

```
@PostMapping(value="/geteventstoday.json")
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView showTodayEvents(ModelAndView model, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException
    {
        //First, we must populate the list of Events 
        List<Events> listEvents = networks.getTodayEvents();
        
        //Second, we put this list in the model and set properties for jquery datatables
                model.addObject("recordsTotal", listEvents.size());
                model.addObject("recordsFiltered", listEvents.size());
                model.addObject("data", listEvents);
             
        //Finally, we return the model
        return model;
    }
```

The file with data table is actually this:

/**

- This data table is used to show the events of current day in
- the today events page.
  */

  var DTevents = false;

  $(document).ready(function() {

  ```
   DTevents = $('#eventsdatageneral').DataTable( 
           { 
               "serverSide": true,
               "ajax":{
                           url: "../geteventstoday.json",
                           type: "post",
                           "data": function (d)
                           {

                           }

                      },

               "columns":  [
                   { "data": "name" },
                   { "data": "os"},
                   { "data": null }, //OS
                   { "data": null }, //FileIntegrity
                   { "data": null }, //services
                   { "data": null }, //runningservice
                   { "data": null}, //tcpservices
                   { "data": null } //applications
               ]
           } );
   } );
  ```

But, of course, with this structure the results is the same of the result table that I show you at the start:

[image: results of query in dt]

and this is not the form that we want.

So, the question is: what I must modify to obtain the results that we want? The DAO? The Controller? The Data Table? And how?

Comment: You might find https://github.com/darrachequesne/spring-data-jpa-datatables very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it appears you want a group concationation function so something like this may work

```
select group_concat(type,','), name,os from <your table>  group by name,os;
```

you will want to change your sql to use the group concatination function to allow for all of the rows to appear on one line

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Uhm seems interesting; now I must only understand how modify my Rowmapper for this query. Thanks a lot.

Comment: if you post your query i can  help. or if this was enough please mark it as answer